# Ios file handling and location access

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am having an ios app that reads contents of a csv file and produces output.When i run the program on a simulator ,i can directly specify the file path(/Users/abc/file.csv).Where to keep these files and access them in a n iphone.We cant specify the static path here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag & drop them to your project, and access them like this:

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *myFile = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"csv"]
```

Comment: Should i drag the file in supporting files folder??

Comment: Wherever you want to put it, but inside the project

Answer (score 0):

If you place the file in your application directory, you can access it by:

```
 NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
 NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"yourfilename" ofType:@"csv"];
```

Answer (score 0):

For reading static files, use the other people's answers.

If you need to write out a file, you need to access the Documents directory.

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.csv"];
```

And then use `NSFileManager` for writing the file. Classes such as `NSDictionary` have helper functions for writing their values to a file, too.